# how to blur the background image only in css

Tags: html, css

Hi i am trying to blur the background image but i think its lacking in doing so. Any help over it will boost my energy for it. Thanks

This my CSS

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width:  100%;
   background: url(img/rsz_1spring.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
 max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;

}
```

I am  trying to apply this but it blur all my webpage instaed of background image only.

```
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
```

Thank you.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar Check the link in the comment above, and tell us if the solution they have suits your needs.

Comment: @RDardelet i am trying to solve this with that link .. lets see.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are applying blur to `<html>` then it will blur your webpage.

Instead of adding background to `<html>` You need to create another `<div>` with in `<body>` with size to that of webpage and add blur to it.

**Example**

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: #fff;
}

.page-bg {
  background: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/general-night-golden-gate-bridge-hd-wallpapers-golden-gate-bridge-wallpaper.jpg');
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1>
This is a title
</h1>

<div class="page-bg">
</div>
```

Comment: @tympazz thank you so much this is awesome... this solves my doubt thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assign id or class attribute to image tag or div containing image then assign css property to that particular image tag or div containing image. You are blurring for whole html that will obviously blur whole webpage.

For eg:

```
<div class="image-container"><img class="blurred" src="..." /></div>
```

either you blur to image-container or to image directly like or image of div

```
.image-container, .blurred, .image-container>img {
   -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
   -moz-filter: blur(5px);
   -o-filter: blur(5px);
   -ms-filter: blur(5px);
   filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for you kind hearted help.. this solves my doubt and query also.. thank you @everyone .:)