# Make background image full page in html

Tags: html, css

[image: background error]

I'm working on this movie website and put a background. 
I want the background to repeat itself and cover the whole page even if I scroll down but for some reason I can't fix it. 
I tried searching for it and tried every solution I got from google but all in vain. This is my code for background image. I tried changing the value of back-ground repeat to repeat-y but still it didn't work. 
Any hints on what to do?

```
/*------ Background image ------*/
.bg-image {
/* The image used */
background-image: url("bgd.jpg");

/* Add the blur effect */
filter: blur(4px);
-webkit-filter: blur(4px);

/* Full height */
height: 100%;


/* Center and scale the image nicely */
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

/* ------------------------ */
```

Comment: If you want the background to repeat set the `background-repeat` to `repeat`

Comment: Moreover, if you want the background to stay like it is when you scroll then use `background-attachment:fixed`

Comment: @AbdullahRazzaki I did try this but not working

Comment: Try: background-repeat: repeat-y;

Comment: @lulius No change :(

Comment: which element have you added the `bg-image` class to? the body?

Comment: Not in body tag.

Comment: <body>
<div class = "bg-image"> </div> </body>
Like this

Comment: You should add it to body tag like `<body class="bg-image">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set background style properties directly with `body` tag.
*Use `background-repeat: repeat`*.Also you can use *`!important`* to overwrite some css property.
i.e

```
body {
/* The image used */
background-image: url("bgd.jpg");



/* Center and scale the image nicely */
background-position: center;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Yes, now it is working but what should I do for the blur effect?

Comment: Because I can't put the blur effect inside body tag since it'll blur the whole website. :(

Comment: Good, You can simply add that CSS with either body tag or with some other class. :)

Comment: By adding a Blur effect in some other class you can then simply use it any where in the web page :)

Comment: This link can also be helpful [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366571/how-to-blur-the-background-image-only-in-css/38366742#38366742]

Answer (score 0):

You should make the div absolute if you want to have the blur

```
.bg-image{
position:absoulte;
width:100%;
height:100%;
left:0;
top:0;
// existing background css
}
```